# Does Python have a rope data structure?

Tags: python, string, data-structures, python-3.x, ropes

In writing some Python code, I came upon a need for a string-like data structure that offers fast insertion into, access to, and deletion from arbitrary positions. The first data structure that came to mind was a [rope](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rope_%28data_structure%29). Does Python have a rope data structure already implemented somewhere? I've looked through the standard library and PyPI, but I haven't seen one. (It doesn't help that there's [a refactoring library](http://rope.sourceforge.net/) for Python by the name of Rope as well as [a company](http://pythonrope.com/) called Python Rope that sells wire rope.)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There isn't one in the standard library, but there are implementations out there, e.g. [`pyropes`](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pyropes/).

---

There's also this [list of various non-built-in data structure implementations for Python](http://web.archive.org/web/20130307213549/http://kmike.ru/python-data-structures/).

Answer (score 2):

Yes! there is one package available at [PyPI.org](https://pypi.org/project/pyropes/) for Rope data structure(named pyropes), written purely in Python 3. You can install it using

```
pip install pyropes
```

It also have full documentation on how to use it. Though it requires Python >=3.6(because it uses f-strings)